# generating random string zsh

Tags: random, zsh

I am trying to generate a random string with the following code:

```
for pic in `ls *.jpg`; do
  rdn=`echo $RANDOM | sha256sum | cut -d" " -f1`
  mv "$pic" ${rnd}.jpg
done
```

This part of the script runs from within a directory containing lots of jpeg files and it should randomize their filenames. The problem is that the `$RANDOM` variable does not update during the iteration, and therefore gives the same hash every time. I tried to use `/dev/urandom`, and it works, but is a lot slower than `$RANDOM`. What can I do to "regenerate" `$RANDOM` every time it is read?

Comment: Works for me... if it's a script, make sure the shebang line says "/bin/bash" instead of "/bin/sh", just in case.

Comment: What did you try with /dev/urandom? If you limit the slice with `dd`, for example, it should be quite fast.

Comment: Also, this line from the bash manual may be relevant: *If RANDOM is unset, it loses its special properties, even if it is subsequently reset.*

Comment: I tried `for pic in `ls *.jpg`; do rnd=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | head -c 20); mv "$pic" ${rnd}.jpg;done;`

Comment: Your approach should work. There must be some other bugs in your script.

Comment: I figured this is zsh specific behavior.

Comment: **Yes this is zsh.** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577117/ https://superuser.com/questions/1210435/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for pic in *.jpg; do # Iterate over the jpgs in the current directory.
  dd if=/dev/urandom count=1 2>/dev/null | sha256sum | ( # Gather 512 bytes from /dev/urandom
    read rnd _ # Read the first "word" in the sha256sum output
    mv "$pic" ${rnd}.jpg # rename the jpg.
  )
done
```

Piping to `read` causes an implicit subshell, so I create an explicit subshell to guarantee I can still access the `rnd` parameter. Also, [don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

By the way, are you sure you don't just want to `base64` the output? It's cheaper than sha256sum by far and I don't see what you're getting out of sha256sum. Plus it'd make the code easier to read:

```
for pic in *.jpg; do
  mv "$pic" "$(base64 </dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | head -c20).jpg"
done
```

Answer (score 7):

On my mac (using macOS High Sierra), the `/dev/urandom` gives me binary bytes, so the above solution results in `tr: Illegal byte sequence`, so I used `base64` to convert bytes to characters:

```
cat /dev/urandom | base64 | tr -dc '0-9a-zA-Z' | head -c100
```

or I found a solution without base64 so you can get punctuation as well:

```
cat /dev/urandom | LC_ALL=C tr -dc '\''[:alnum:]\!\@\#$\-\.\,'\'' | head -c40
```

Comment: to have a new line after the generated random string (for more easy copy paste) I used sed: `cat /dev/urandom | base64 | tr -dc '0-9a-zA-Z' | head -c15 | sed 's/$/\n/'`

Comment: You don't need to pipe to `tr` if first piping to `base64` since it already outputs ascii bytes. Also if you want "more easy copy paste", just do `cat /dev/urandom | base64 | head -c100 | pbcopy`

Answer (score 6):

You can do this more simply just using cat, tr and head. For example:

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '0-9a-zA-Z' | head -c100
```

The `tr` command in this pipeline will delete any character from stdin which does *not* match the specified character set. The `head` will print the first 100 characters and then exit, terminating the overall command.

This will generate a 100 character string containing alphanumeric characters. To make this into a rename you just need to use command substitution:

```
for file in *.jpg
    mv -n ${file} $(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '0-9a-zA-Z' | head -c100).jpg
```

In zsh a `for` loop with a single statement does not need to be surrounded with `do` or `done`. The `-n` flag to mv will prevent it from overwriting an existing file - just in case you get really unlucky with the random strings.