# References to $RANDOM in subshells all returning identical values

Tags: shell, random, zsh

The following short script prints a random ten-digit binary number:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
point=''
for i in `seq 1 10`
do
    echo $RANDOM >/dev/null
    point=$point`if [ $RANDOM -gt 16383 ]; then echo 0; else echo 1; fi`
done
echo $point
```

However, if I remove the apparently useless `echo $RANDOM >/dev/null` line, the script always prints either `1111111111` or `0000000000`.

Why?

Comment: The title of the question is a bit funny now! If I had known to title the question so specifically as that, I probably wouldn't have needed to ask a question...

Comment: Admittedly so. The question, though -- if you'd seen this title when you were searching for duplicates before asking (you *did* search for duplicates, right?), would you have recognized it as your problem? (If not, perhaps the "in subshells" needs to be backed out).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I did search for duplicates, and found a few that definitely weren't related. I would have at least clicked on this title if I'd seen it in the results. =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the man page:

> The values of RANDOM form an intentionally-repeatable pseudo-random sequence; subshells  that  reference
>   RANDOM  will result in identical pseudo-random values unless the value of RANDOM is referenced or seeded
>   in the parent shell in between subshell invocations.

The "useless" call to `echo` provides the reference that allows the subshell induced by the command substitution to produce a different value each time.

Answer (score 9):

Subshells (as created by backticks, or their modern replacement `$()`) execute in a different context from the parent shell -- meaning that when they exit, all process-local state changes -- *including* the random number generator's state -- are thrown away.

Reading from `$RANDOM` inside the parent shell updates the RNG's state, which is why the `echo $RANDOM >/dev/null` has an effect.

That said, don't do that. Do something like this, which has no subshells at all:

```
point=
for ((i=0; i<10; i++)); do
  point+=$(( (RANDOM > 16383) ? 0 : 1 ))
done
```

If you test this generating more than 10 digits -- try, say, 1000, or 10000 -- you'll also find that it performs far better than the original did.

Comment: It was a tough choice between this answer and the other one. The other included the most relevant documentation quote; but I greatly appreciate the alternative code suggestion as well.

Comment: Definitely use the subshell-free code; I just focused on explaining the observed behavior.

Comment: Hmm. Actually, this could be shortened by using a ternary; I'm tempted to revise...

Comment: Could also just do `point+=$(( (RANDOM >> 14) && 1 ))`, and not need the ternary either.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have stated, Zsh `$RANDOM` doesn't behave the same as bash and repeats the same sequence if invoked within a subshell. That behavior can be seen with this simple example:

```bash
$ # bash: different numbers; zsh: all the same number
$ for i in {0..99}; do echo $(echo $RANDOM); done
22865
22865
...
22865
```

What the other answers don't cover is how do get around this behavior in Zsh. While `echo $RANDOM >/dev/null` helps if you know `$RANDOM` was invoked, it doesn't help much if it's tucked away in a function you're writing. That puts extra burden on the caller to do this weird echo:

```bash
function rolldice {
    local i times=${1:-1} sides=${2:-6}
    for i in $(seq $times); do
      echo $(( 1 + $RANDOM % $sides ))
    done
}

# all 4 players rolled the exact same thing!
for i in {1..4}; do echo $(rolldice 10); done

# seriously ...
for i in {1..4}; do echo $(rolldice 10); echo $RANDOM >/dev/null; done
```

While it's more expensive (slower) to do, you could get around this by running `$RANDOM` within a new Zsh session to get results similar to Bash:

```bash
function rolldice {
    local i times=${1:-1} sides=${2:-6}
    for i in $(seq $times); do
      echo $(( 1 + $(zsh -c 'echo $RANDOM') % $sides ))
    done
}

# now all 4 players rolled different results!
for i in {1..4}; do echo $(rolldice 10); done
```

There are other better ways than using `$RANDOM` to get a uniformly random number in Zsh, but this works in a pinch. One popular alternative is `random=$(od -vAn -N4 -t u4 < /dev/urandom); echo $random`.