# Why does sourcing shell script in another shell script return same result every time?

Tags: bash, shell

Say I have a shell script `function.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

n=$(( RANDOM % 100 ))
echo $n
```

I have another scripts called `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
    output=$(source "$1")
    echo $output
    if [[ $output -eq 42 ]]
    then
        break
    else
        continue
    fi

done
```

When I run `source test.sh function.sh` I expect roughly 100 lines of output until the while loop breaks, but what actually happens is an infinite loop with the same number outputted every time.

Where's the error in my code?

I suspect `$(source "$1")` is the culprit -- for some reason, maybe the seed for the random number generation ensures the same number is returned for each loop of the while loop?

Comment: Works for me. Start a new bash and try again.

Comment: Only took 117 iterations! Run `bash test.sh function.sh`

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Rankin -- what is `$i`?

Comment: That was supposed to be `$1`, but the use of `source test.sh function.sh` was correct as `function.sh` would become the positional parameter of `test.sh` if your current shell is bash. (so I don't know why it didn't work for you unless your current shell isn't bash) What does `echo $SHELL` show?

Comment: FWIW, your suggestion to use `bash` works. `/bin/zsh` is what my `$SHELL` is

Comment: FYI, it seems to be related to the seeding of `RANDOM` under zsh. Running `unset o; unset n ; while ; do o=$( source function.sh; ) ; echo $o;  done` will always output the same number, but `unset o; unset n ; while ; do x=$(( RANDOM )) ; o=$( source function.sh; ) ; echo $o;  done` will work as expected. The trouble is not related to the while loop, as it can be reproduced without any loop.  It's clearly linked to the sourcing context _in a subshell_ under zsh.

Comment: You can directly reproduce it under zsh with a simple `y=$(source function.sh); echo $y;`. It will always output the same number, while `source function.sh` will work as expected. My guess: The '`rand()` three calls' are not applied in a sourced call from a subshell, and it we always get the _current_ next iteration of the pseudorand generator (`rand()` hidden state is loose).

Comment: There was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577117/references-to-random-in-subshells-all-returning-identical-values) on the case of `RANDOM` in a _zsh_ subshell, with a corresponding [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32577518/3641635) from @CharlesDuffy. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32577517/3641635) gives the man page details explaining the thing, there is no seeding in that case. I guess we can mark this question as a dup of that one ?